# Node & Mongo db.open giving undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

Following [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/iksose/9401758), when running my server.js file I am getting the following error

```
self.s.pool = new Pool(Object.^assign(self.s.options, options, {bson:this.s.                       

TypeError: undefined is not a function
"
```

Seems to be a problem with my `db.open()` function. However, I am unsure as to whether it is because a connection can not be made to the database or something else.

I can log the server and db objects, so not sure where the undefined error is coming from. It doesn't log the error message contained in the db.open function so something seems to break before then.

Any help would be great, below is my code

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    movies = require('./routes/movies.js');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.get('/movies',movies.findAll);
app.get('/movies/:id',movies.findById);
app.post('/movies', movies.addMovie);
app.put('/movies/:id',movies.updateMovie);
app.delete('/movies/:id',movies.deleteMovie);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

**routes/movies.js**

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('moviedb', server);


db.open(function(err,db){
  if(!err)
  {
    console.log('Connected to "moviesdb" database');
    db.collection('movies',{strict:true},function(err,collection){
      if(err)
      {
        console.log("The 'movies' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
        populateDB();
      }
    });
  }
});

exports.findAll = function(req,res){
  db.collection('movies',function(err,collection){
    collection.find().toArray(function(err,items){
      res.send(items);
    });
  });
}

exports.findById = function(req,res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log('Retrieving movie: ' + id);
  db.collection('movies',function(err,collection){
    collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err,item){
      res.send(item);
    });
  });
}

exports.addMovie = function(req,res){
  var movie = req.body;
  console.log('Adding movie: ' + JSON.stringify(movie));
  db.collection('movies',function(err,collection){
    collection.insert(movie,{'safe':true},function(err,result){
      if(err)
      {
        res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('Success:' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
        res.send(result[0]);
      }
    });
  });
}

exports.updateMovie = function(req,res){
    var id = req.params.id,
        movie = req.body;
    console.log('Updating movie: ' + id);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(movie));
    db.collection('movies',function(err,collection){
      collection.update({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)},movie,{'safe':true},function(err,result){
        if(err)
        {
          console.log('Error updating movie: ' + err);
          res.send({'error':'An error has occured'});
        }
        else
        {
          console.log('' + result + ' document(s) updated');
          res.send(movie);
        }
      });
    });
}

exports.deleteMovie = function(req,res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log('Deleting movie: ' + id);
  db.collection('movies',function(err,collection){
      collection.remove({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
        if(err)
        {
          res.send({'error':'An error has occurred - ' + err});
        }
        else
        {
          console.log('' + result + ' document(s) deleted');
          res.send(req.body); 
        }
      });
  });
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Populate database with sample data -- Only used once: the first time the application is started.
var populateDB = function() {

    var movies = [
    {
        name: "Titanic",
        release: "2009",
        description: "description....",
        picture: "titanic-poster.jpg"
    },
     {
        name: "Jaws",
        release: "2000",
        description: "description....",
        picture: "jaws-poster.jpg"
    },
      {
        name: "Halloween",
        release: "1992",
        description: "description....",
        picture: "halloween-poster.jpg"
    }
    ];

    db.collection('movies', function(err, collection) {
        collection.insert(movies, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {});
    });

}
```

Comment: Presumably the `Object.^assign` is a typo?

Comment: yes but that's the actual error message not my code!

Comment: @IsiahMeadows that's just his error report showing where the error is. The actual code doesn't have the "^". I have this issue too. Any help would be great